# better way to loop a dict in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I am working on a flask app that gets data from a database and should render this in on a page template.
It is working okish, but there is the request to display data differently. I am now looking how I can do this best.

The data is an example, my data set has up to 20 columns and more than 1000 rows

Assume the SQL table looks like this:

| State | City | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alabama | Huntsville | 220k |
| Alabama | Montgomery | 199k |
| Alabama | Birmingham | 198k |
| Alabama | Mobile | 185k |
| Alaska | Anchorage | 288k |
| Alaska | Fairbanks | 33k |
| Alaska | Juneau | 32k |
| Arizona | Phoenix | 1,625k |
| Arizona | Tucson | 543k |
| Arizona | Mesa | 509k |

The data is going directly to a dict which is passed to jinja2

```
cursor.execute("SELECT State , City , Population from table")
result = cursor.fetchall()
return render_template('template.html', results = results)
```

in Jinja2 it looks like this:

```
    {% for result in results %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{result['State']}}</td>     
            <td>{{result['City']}}</td>
            <td>{{result['Population']}}</td>
        </tr>        
    {% endfor %}
```

Now the request is to deliver the output in div with a structure like this:

```
Alabama 
 -- Huntsville 220k
 -- Montgomery 199k
 -- Birmingham 198k
Alaska
 -- Anchorage 228k
 -- Fairbanks 33k
 -- Juneau 32k
```

The jinja loop could be something link this

```
    {% for states in results %}
        <div>
            <div>{{result['State']}}</div>     
            <div>
              {% for cities in results %}
{% if states['State'] == cities ['State'] %}
                <div>--</div>
                <div>{{result['City']}}</div>
                <div>{{result['Population']}}</div>
{% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>        
    {% endfor %}
```

what is the best way to loop this dictionary again? Would it be better if the data would be prepared differently before putting into the template?

I am not looking for the exact code, but some input what could be a great approach.

Comment: maybe you should first group data - to create nested dictionary like `{"Alabama": [...], "Alaska": [...]}` (ie. using `pandas.groupby()`) or nested list like `[("Alabama", [...]), ("Alaska", [...]), ...]` (ie. using `itertools.group()`) - and later you could send it to template

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be simpler first group data and lated send it to template.

You may use `itertools.groupby(data, key)` to group it

```
groups = itertools.groupby(results, lambda row:row['State'])
```

---

Minimal working example

```
results = [
    {'State': 'Alabama', 'City': 'Huntsville', 'Population': '220k'},
    {'State': 'Alabama', 'City': 'Montgomery', 'Population': '199k'},
    {'State': 'Alabama', 'City': 'Birmingham', 'Population': '198k'},
    {'State': 'Alabama', 'City': 'Mobile', 'Population': '185k'},
    {'State': 'Alaska', 'City': 'Anchorage', 'Population': '288k'},
    {'State': 'Alaska', 'City': 'Fairbanks', 'Population': '33k'},
    {'State': 'Alaska', 'City': 'Juneau', 'Population': '32k'},
    {'State': 'Arizona', 'City': 'Phoenix', 'Population': '1,625k'},
    {'State': 'Arizona', 'City': 'Tucson', 'Population': '543k'},
    {'State': 'Arizona', 'City': 'Mesa', 'Population': '509k'}
]
    
#print(results)

import itertools

groups = itertools.groupby(results, lambda row:row['State'])

# conver only to display it in one line but `for`-loop doesn't need it
#groups = [(state, list(data)) for state, data in groups]
#print(groups)

# run similar loops in template
for state, data in groups:
    print(state)
    for item in data:
        print('---', item['City'], item['Population'])
```

Results:

```
Alabama
--- Huntsville 220k
--- Montgomery 199k
--- Birmingham 198k
--- Mobile 185k
Alaska
--- Anchorage 288k
--- Fairbanks 33k
--- Juneau 32k
Arizona
--- Phoenix 1,625k
--- Tucson 543k
--- Mesa 509k
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that nested loop, you can use the `loop.nextitem` and `loop.previtem` special variable to asses if you need to display the state or not:

```
{% for result in results | sort(attribute="State") %}
  {% if not loop.previtem or loop.previtem.State != result.State %}
    <div>
      <div>{{ result.State }}</div>     
      <div>
  {% endif %}
        <div>--</div>
        <div>{{ result.City }}</div>
        <div>{{ result.Population }}</div>
  {% if not loop.nextitem or loop.nextitem.State != result.State %}
      </div>
    </div>   
  {% endif %}     
{% endfor %}
```

---

Another way would be to, first, select the unique states, with the [`unique` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.unique), and then, only select the elements having those state, with the [`selectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr):

```
{% for state in results | unique(attribute="State") %}
<div>
  <div>{{ state.State }}</div>     
  <div>
    {% for city in results | selectattr('State', '==', state.State) %}
      <div>--</div>
      <div>{{ city.City }}</div>
      <div>{{ city.Population }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>      
{% endfor %}
```